# caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mypackage.LoginActivity" on path: DexPathList

Tags: android

I know few people have asked this question before but I didn't find their solutions useful for me.

Please see my build path jar in below image--

[image: Build path jars]

Following is my complete error log:

`05-16 17:32:13.988: E/AndroidRuntime(19650): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-16 17:32:13.988: E/AndroidRuntime(19650): Process: com.mypackage.hobnobpal, PID: 19650
05-16 17:32:13.988: E/AndroidRuntime(19650): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.mypackage.hobnobpal/com.mypackage.quickevent.LoginActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mypackage.quickevent.LoginActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mypackage.hobnobpal-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.mypackage.hobnobpal-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
05-16 17:32:13.988: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2124)
05-16 17:32:13.988: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247)
05-16 17:32:13.988: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-16 17:32:13.988: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
05-16 17:32:13.988: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-16 17:32:13.988: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-16 17:32:13.988: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5111)
05-16 17:32:13.988: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-16 17:32:13.988: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-16 17:32:13.988: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:806)
05-16 17:32:13.988: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
05-16 17:32:13.988: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-16 17:32:13.988: E/AndroidRuntime(19650): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mypackage.quickevent.LoginActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mypackage.hobnobpal-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.mypackage.hobnobpal-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
05-16 17:32:13.988: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
05-16 17:32:13.988: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
05-16 17:32:13.988: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
05-16 17:32:13.988: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
05-16 17:32:13.988: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2115)`

Following is my AndroidManifest file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mypackage.hobnobpal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NETWORK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECIEVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.pushnotification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.pushnotification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.CreateAccountActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_create_account"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.UserHomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_user_home"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.UserProfileActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_user_profile"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.AddFriendActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_friend"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.CreateEventActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_create_event"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.WeatherLocationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_weather_location"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.NightWeatherActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_night_weather"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.InviteGuestsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_invite_guests"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.FacebookLoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_facebook_login" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.CalenderActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_calender"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.ViewEventActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_view_event"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.ChatActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_chat"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.GuestChatListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_guest_chat_list"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.ChatPageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_chat_page"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.FriendChatActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_friend_chat"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.ConversationChatActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_conversation_chat"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.ChangePasswordActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_change_password"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.NotificationPageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_notification_page"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.EventsNotificationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_events_notification"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.EventNotiActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_event_noti"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.FriendNotiActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_friend_noti"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.MyProfileActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_my_profile"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.GuestSelectActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_guest_select"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.ForgotPasswordActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_forgot_password"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.EventListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_event_list"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.EventHomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_event_home"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.WeatherActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_weather"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.FriendsProfileActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_friends_profile"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.FriendListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_friend_list"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.CheckInActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_check_in"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.EditProfileActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_profile"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickvent.pushnotification.RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickvent.pushnotification.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickvent.pushnotification.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.mypackage.quickvent.pushnotification" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.mypackage.quickvent.pushnotification.GCMNotificationIntentService" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.MutualFriendsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_mutual_friends"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.AddGuestActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_guest"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.AddHostActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_host"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.EditEventActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_event"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.VerifyPasswordActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_verify_password"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.ChatDetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_chat_detail"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.DeleteEventActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_delete_event"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.EventCancelActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_event_cancel"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.GroupChatActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_group_chat"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.CheckedInGuestListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_checked_in_guest_list"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.GuestListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_guest_list"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.FragmentTabActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fragment_tab"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.ContactsTabActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_contacts_tab"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.QuickventFriendsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_quickvent_friends"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.ChatImageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_chat_image"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.ChatService"
            android:label="My Service"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.GroupChatDetail"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_group_chat_detail"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.ParticipantsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_participants"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.ActivityActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.ImageDisplayActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.DetailActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.LikeDetailsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.FriendChatActivity$ChatMessageReceiver"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="action" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickvent.utilities.NetworkChangeReceiver"
            android:label="NetworkChangeReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.PostReviewActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_post_review"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.NewFragmentTabActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".InvitedListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_invited_list" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ZoomActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="locked" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TermsAndCondition"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_terms_and_condition"
             android:screenOrientation="locked" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please help, Thanks.

Comment: show your manifest file please.

Comment: Did you add your activity in the manifest?

Comment: @Sharad Chauhan Plz see the edited.

Comment: @MachoProgrammer Yes.

Comment: "com.mypackage.quickevent.LoginActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mypackage.hobnobpal-2.apk"] Double check your package name and activity name. is it coming under that package name or not.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using a relative path to your activity in the manifest?

```
<activity
    android:name=".LoginActivity"
```

If you are absolutely sure that path to your activity in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file is correct, try updating java to latest version (you can download it from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html)). It helped me once on my windows computer

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you forgot to add your activity in the manifest like this

```
<activity
    android:name="com.mypackage.quickevent.LoginActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_event_noti"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
</activity>
```

Comment: I added LoginActivity in my manifest file, plz check my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

I think your package name is wrong. it should be `com.mypackage.quickevent` instead of `com.mypackage.hobnobpal`

So replace,

```
package="com.mypackage.hobnobpal"
```

with

```
package="com.mypackage.quickevent"
```

And try again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but my project contains multiple packages and LoginActivity is in "com.mypackage.quickevent" packege.